# C#: throw invalid expression compilation

Tags: c#

I'm using this code in order to check `queryable` value:

```
visitor.Queryable = queryable ?? throw new Exception("error message");
```

I'm getting a compilation error:

> error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'throw'

I'm using 4.5.2 .net framework.
Any ideas?

Comment: [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1762772/1997232).

Comment: It will be useful to also mention in what VS and C# you are working with

Comment: `throw` doesn't return a value, which on compilers older than C#7 is not supported with `??`

Comment: @RufusL: That doesn't matter; this is valid C# 7 code, but won't work with other versions.

Comment: The version of the framework you're targeting doesn't matter. The version of the compiler you're using very much does. If you're using a C# 7 compiler, this should be fine. If you're using C# 6 or earlier, it won't be.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**This feature is only available post C# 7.0**. See under [Throw exception of  What's New in C# 7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#throw-expressions).

If you are using an older VS and want to enable C# 7 features: Have a look at [How to use c#7 with Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39461407/6400526) if not in VS 2017.

---

If you are working with a previous version of the C# compiler, as you must be due to the error then you cannot use the `??` operator this way as the throw does not return a right operand value. As the [C# Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) say:

> It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right operand.

The pattern is like this:

```
var result = someObject ?? valueToAssignIfWasNull;
```

To solve it write instead:

```
if(queryable == null)
{
    throw new Exception("error message");
}
visitor.Queryable = queryable;
```

Comment: I thought I saw that somewhere in ``C# 7.1``

Comment: Than the question stands whats wrong with OPs code?

Comment: @RandRandom - probably OP isn't using VS 2017 :)

Comment: I think that he should avoid doing it, anyway

Comment: @MarcoSalerno - wouldn't really say that... If it was added to the language as a valid compilation option at C# 7.0 then I guess there are good enough reasons to do so :) What I do agree is that it is a personal preference.

Comment: Yup, as I said "i think", I find it syntactically unclear

Comment: I would recommend removing all of the first part of this answer. Basically everything above the dividing line becomes irrelevant when the part below is taken into consideration.

Comment: @JonSkeet - was just rethinking the answer myself

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted the accepted, but I'll also put forward a workaround:

```
private Queryable NullAlternative()
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("Null Queryable not supported at this time.");
}
```

Then, elsewhere, you can say

```
visitor.Queryable = queryable ?? NullAlternative();
```

This is nice if you can't upgrade to VS2017 but don't want to lose the slick conditional syntax, and it has the added benefit of leaving it open to some kind of null-object pattern in the future (such as initializing an empty queryable).